# Comparing strings, returned from php, in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, html, string, if-statement

I am returning a string form php and compare it with another string in jQuery. I am 100% certain that the strings do match (well, at least are of the same value...), but still my if-clause thinks otherwise.

This is the part of my php-script that sets the returning value:

```
if (!$result){
        echo "false";
        exit();
    }
```

This is my jQuery that performs the matching:

```
$.post("registeraccount.php",$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
        //alert the response from the server
        alert(msg + " = " + (msg == "false"));
        if(msg == "false"){
            $("#adminarea").html("Error");

        }else{
            $("#adminarea").html("Success");
        }

   });
```

No matter that the strings are equal or not equal, it's always "Success" that is printed on the web page.

In the alert I get the following result "false = false". Hence, (msg == "false") is false.

How come the strings are not true when they are equal and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure 'msg' is a string?

Comment: Have you checked for stray whitespace in `msg`?

Comment: @silverstrike, doesn't 'echo "false"' imply that it is a string?

Comment: @mu is too short , how do I check for stray whitespace?

Comment: Not necessarily. The server echo the word false, but do you pass false or "false"?

Comment: I think it would help if you changed your test string to something less confusing like "test". You know that can only evaluate to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that the reason is that `msg`, your server output, is never *exactly* "false", due to some line endings that are added or similar things in you PHP script (you could check if `msg` has the length you expect to verify this hypothesis). In this case, you could try using this:

```
 if (msg.match(/false/)) {
```

which does a somewhat less strict comparison if you want, ensuring that the output contains the string "false" (at any position). If it works, I suggest that you use instead this comparison:

```
 if (msg.match(/^false$/)) {
```

which guarantees that `false` be a whole line of your text.

Comment: or `if ($.trim(msg) == "false") {` or `if (msg.indexOf('false') > -1) {`

Comment: @sergio, msg.match(/false/) worked but msg.match(/^false$/) didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

You have to use `===` to compare for equality in JavaScript.

If you have time have a look at Crockford video series on javascript. It covers this and a lot of other javascript topics.

Comment: Didn't work. I don't think it should be necesseary, should it? Googling around for comparing strings in javascript, most posts say "==".